# Calibre - no available format

Tags: calibre, file-format

I have been using calibre in Mac for a long time. Recently I subscribed to iCloud and store my Calibre folder in iCloud. Somehow, plenty of books in my library cannot be open (mainly PDFs) and the error message says there is no available format. The PDFs are still in my library but when I check in Calibre the book is shown as being in "iCloud" format, for which there is of course no available format. Any help on how to solve this problem?

Comment: If you have local backups, or can download the files to disk from iCloud and use *that* for the Calibre library, do so -- otherwise, it appears iCloud is damaging files, and you've lost data.